# javascript array swapping function

Tags: javascript, arrays

just trying to create a simple array swap in javascript and keep getting an error.

```
var a = [4,1,2,3];

function swap(x,y){
    var src=x;
    var dest = y;
    var tmp = a[src];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = tmp;
    return a;
}

document.write(swap(0,1));
```

Why is it this is not working? any help appreciated. thank you

Comment: What error? I don't see any error in this.

Comment: It does work. Don't see anything wrong.

Comment: An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing

Comment: Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccp1quu9/

Comment: Nothing wrong with the function you wrote

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to work. You can also add this `swap` method to `Array.prototype`:

```
Array.prototype.swap = function(pos1, pos2) {
  this[pos1] = this.splice(pos2, 1, this[pos1])[0];
}
// usage:
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4].swap(0, 1); //=> [2,1,3,4]
```